# Where can I find the "help set" of commands with examples for the monero cli wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cli

Is there a page where I can see all the help set commands for the monero cli wallet?

Comment: "Where can I find... Is there a page..." ? Just type `help set` - that displays all the variables that can be set and documents each. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I meant if there was a wiki page or something.

Comment: "a wiki page or something" <- Not that I've come across. `help set` will always have the most accurate / up-to-date information.

Comment: ok. reason why I ask is, so I can easily do a ctrl+find. I'm not going to read every line in help set.  thanks.

Comment: almost every terminal I've ever used has search functionality

Comment: Your gratuitous answer below just highlights the point, as it will undoubtedly not be maintained on this SE - the *actual* built-in documentation will always be most accurate / up-to-date information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monero cli wallet output of the "help set" settings is below since its not found anywhere in cyberspace. Updated as of 2021-Jan-21.

```
Command usage:
  set <option> [<value>]

Command description:
  Available options:
   seed language
     Set the wallet's seed language.

   always-confirm-transfers <1|0>
     Whether to confirm unsplit txes.

   print-ring-members <1|0>
     Whether to print detailed information about ring members during confirmation.

   store-tx-info <1|0>
     Whether to store outgoing tx info (destination address, payment ID, tx secret key) for future reference.

   default-ring-size <n>
     Set the default ring size (obsolete).

   auto-refresh <1|0>
     Whether to automatically synchronize new blocks from the daemon.

   refresh-type <full|optimize-coinbase|no-coinbase|default>
     Set the wallet's refresh behaviour.

   priority [0|1|2|3|4]
     Set the fee to default/unimportant/normal/elevated/priority.

   confirm-missing-payment-id <1|0> (obsolete)
   ask-password <0|1|2   (or never|action|decrypt)>
     action: ask the password before many actions such as transfer, etc
     decrypt: same as action, but keeps the spend key encrypted in memory when not needed

   unit <monero|millinero|micronero|nanonero|piconero>
     Set the default monero (sub-)unit.

   min-outputs-count [n]
     Try to keep at least that many outputs of value at least min-outputs-value.

   min-outputs-value [n]
     Try to keep at least min-outputs-count outputs of at least that value.

   merge-destinations <1|0>
     Whether to merge multiple payments to the same destination address.

   confirm-backlog <1|0>
     Whether to warn if there is transaction backlog.

   confirm-backlog-threshold [n]
     Set a threshold for confirm-backlog to only warn if the transaction backlog is greater than n blocks.

   confirm-export-overwrite <1|0>
     Whether to warn if the file to be exported already exists.

   refresh-from-block-height [n]
     Set the height before which to ignore blocks.

   auto-low-priority <1|0>
     Whether to automatically use the low priority fee level when it's safe to do so.

   segregate-pre-fork-outputs <1|0>
     Set this if you intend to spend outputs on both Monero AND a key reusing fork.

   key-reuse-mitigation2 <1|0>
     Set this if you are not sure whether you will spend on a key reusing Monero fork later.

   subaddress-lookahead <major>:<minor>
     Set the lookahead sizes for the subaddress hash table.

   segregation-height <n>
     Set to the height of a key reusing fork you want to use, 0 to use default.

   ignore-fractional-outputs <1|0>
     Whether to ignore fractional outputs that result in net loss when spending due to fee.

   ignore-outputs-above <amount>
     Ignore outputs of amount above this threshold when spending. Value 0 is translated to the maximum value (18 million) which disables this filter.

   ignore-outputs-below <amount>
     Ignore outputs of amount below this threshold when spending.

   track-uses <1|0>
     Whether to keep track of owned outputs uses.

   setup-background-mining <1|0>
     Whether to enable background mining. Set this to support the network and to get a chance to receive new monero.

   device-name <device_name[:device_spec]>
     Device name for hardware wallet.

   export-format <"binary"|"ascii">
     Save all exported files as binary (cannot be copied and pasted) or ascii (can be).

   persistent-rpc-client-id <1|0>
     Whether to keep using the same client id for RPC payment over wallet restarts.

   auto-mine-for-rpc-payment-threshold <float>
     Whether to automatically start mining for RPC payment if the daemon requires it.

   credits-target <unsigned int>
    The RPC payment credits balance to target (0 for default).

   inactivity-lock-timeout <unsigned int>
     How many seconds to wait before locking the wallet (0 to disable).
```